# Pressing Enter key with an external keyboard doesn't send SMS on Panasonic P100

Tags: sms, external-keyboard

I am using a Panasonic P100. I want to use an external keyboard to SMS to my friend, but the Enter key is not working to send SMS.

Comment: Does the Enter key work in other apps, such as a browser (when entering a URL)? If yes, the problem is with your SMS app. You've got to change it. There *might* be a setting in your SMS app about Enter, but I doubt that.

Comment: We might need more info, what is the name of the SMS app? Also, I assume without the external keyboard, the software keyboard will show "Send" button (or send the SMS when the Enter key is pressed) inside the SMS app?

Comment: Messages is the name of application.It is pre install in mobile

Answer (score 0):

The Enter key can produce 10 (hex 0A), 13 (hex 0D) or 10-13 (2 characters, 0A, then 0D), depending on the operating system it was actually designed for.  The SMS app may be looking specifically for 10 (0A), because that's the Linux EOL (end-of-line) code (and Android is running in a Linux OS).  Use the mouse to click the (in most SMS apps) forward arrow on the screen.  (Or try alt-10 - hold the alt key while pressing 1, then 0, in turn, then release the alt key.  That produces the Linux EOL character.)